# In a RESTful API how should you handle optional query parameters

Tags: javascript, .net, rest

I'm currently dealing with a .net API that aims to be RESTful. One of the endpoints I'm working with has two optional query parameters. The following usage is allowed:

```
/endpoint/search
/endpoint/search?from=01/02/23
/endpoint/search?from=01/02/23&to=01/03/23
```

This endpoint however returns a 400 when you do not provide a value for these optional query params but the keys still exist. Since I primarily work in JS, having the query params either not exist or have a value of undefined are realistically the same thing this seems odd to me that it would return a 400.

I.e.

```
/endpoint/search?from=undefined&to=undefined // 400 response
```

I've tried to scour the internet for an answer. I've looked into OpenAPI specification and the REST rfc but I can't find any relevant passages. I'm of the opinion this is making an endpoint overly restrictive and it should handle undefined as a value. What is the correct approach as per spec if possible?

Comment: How specifically does the server-side code define the values it expects?  Is there a specific server-side operation which produces the error?

Comment: Or maybe I'm misunderstanding you.... Are you saying that `/endpoint/search?from=01/02/23` *does* work (though it really should be URL-encoded), but `/endpoint/search?from=01/02/23&to=undefined` *doesn't* work?  If that's the case then I imagine you should just omit the `to=undefined` part.  `undefined` means something in JavaScript, but that meaning isn't universally shared outside of JavaScript.  For a URL I'd expect the value to just be omitted entirely, or if it is included it would just be empty.

Comment: Yes there is. They define it as optional string. The error I get back is `The value 'undefined' is not valid.`

Comment: I've not got a problem with making this work. It's purely a standards question

Comment: In that case, in terms of standards the string `undefined` does not represent a date value.  For an optional value you'd either omit the key/value entirely or include the key but with no value.

Comment: That's my thinking too but in my world, undefined is the same as no value

Comment: *"but in my world, undefined is the same as no value"* - You can certainly write custom logic to allow this.  But outside of your world these two are not the same thing.  The server-side code is receiving the string value `"undefined"` and trying to parse it as a date.  `undefined` means something in JavaScript, but JavaScript is not the only tool being used here.

Answer (score 2):

If the API allows values, then I would strongly expect the values to have to match the expected values or not be present at all

In your example the value is not undefined. It is the string `"undefined"` and the api expects `\d{1,2}\/d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}` or no parameter at all or it will correctly give status ***400 Bad Request*** or similar

If your description of the rest endpoint is correct, then I would code it like this (perhaps with sanity check that if you have to, you must also have from)

```js
const url = new URL(`https://endpoint.com/endpoint/search`);
let from='01/02/23', to;
if (from) url.searchParams.set('from', from)
if (to) url.searchParams.set('to', to)
console.log(url.toString())
```

Comment: Maybe I've not worded this well. I'm essentially asking is a 400 response correct when the query param value is undefined considering its optional

Comment: Yes. Because it is not undefined. It is `"undefined"` and the api expects `\d{1,2}\/d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}`

Answer (score 1):

> What is the correct approach as per spec if possible?

I don't like your odds of finding a spec.

You certainly shouldn't be able to find a credible REST or HTTP reference, for this reason: HTTP defines the semantics of messages about resources, but doesn't actually constraint resource design, resource identifier design, or the semantics of either of these.

From the perspective of HTTP, the target uri is a whole indivisible thing.  General purpose HTTP components are not supposed to be parsing the URI to derive information that will change local behaviors.

(This was something of a problem for a time with web caches, which had some unfortunate ideas about what it meant for a URI to include a query part.)

> having the query params either not exist or have a value of undefined are realistically the same thing

From the perspective of HTTP, these aren't the same thing at all.  See [RFC 3986 Normalization and Comparison](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-6) to get a sense for what kinds of assumptions general purpose components are expected to make.

What you are really asking for here is a standard that constrains how resources are identified in models; does the existence of a resource identified by `/endpoint/search?from=01/02/23&to=01/03/23` mean that there also [rfc:2119:SHOULD](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119#section-3) be a resource identified by `/endpoint/search?from=undefined&to=undefined`, and if so what representations should it have?

You might be able to find some design guidelines shared by specific communities; for example, I wouldn't be shocked there is a guideline that a lot of Rails projects opt into, or guidelines shared within the OpenAPI community, in much the same way that communities might share a coding style guide.

That said, you should probably make sure that you are familiar with Postel's Law / The Robustness Principle, and it's consequences *as experienced on the world wide web*, before getting deeply invested in a stance for whether a resource model should or should not support this particular edge case.

---

All that said, HTTP 404 would probably be a better choice than HTTP 400 for responding when the URI in the request doesn't actually match a resource on the server, because general purpose web caches will be able to re-use the 404 response when appropriate.